# Minimum IOS version for Adobe Air App

Tags: ios, air, stage3d

I am writing an app for IOS using Adobe Air 3.2 using the new stage 3D feature. What is the minimum version of IOS that I can target?

Also in order to target the new Ipad 3 it seems that you need to instruct the compiler to reference IOS 5.1. Will this mean that if I compile with that setting I wont be able to run my app on lower IOS versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) iOS 4 and above is stated [in the specs](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/tech-specs.html)

2) You can run on any version above your deployment target, which I assume is iOS 4.0 because of what the above tech specs state, regardless of the version you compile against.

Comment: Thanks Mate...for some reason I missed that document.

Answer (score 5):

In AIR SDK 3.3 and newer, you can now specify the minimumosversion supported in the iphone additions tag of the application descriptor. These settings are passed into the Info.plist file in the .ipa file.

In case you are using an iOS 5.0 sdk specific feature in your app, you can set this value to 5.0 in the air application descriptor .xml file:

```
<iPhone>
    <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[
        <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
        <array>
            <string>1</string>
            <string>2</string>
        </array>
        <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>5.0</string>
    ]]></InfoAdditions>
    <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
</iPhone>
```